# Java method stuck in endless loop while validating input

Tags: java

Somehow I am getting some funny play here and I just cant see why.

This method is supposed to make sure that the input is either y or n, and is NOT blank. 
I should note this is for school, and the 2 separate error outputs are required.

When I enter a blank line, I get exactly  that at the console- a blank line. 
After that point, or after a time where I purposely enter bad data, such as x, the very next time I enter a valid data, like y or n, I continue to get the bad data in an endless loop.

What have I done wrong?

```
public static boolean getContinue(Scanner sc)
   {
   boolean decision = false;
   System.out.println("Continue? Y/N: ");
   String userChoice = sc.next();
   boolean isValid = false;
   while (isValid == false)
   {
       if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
       {
           decision = true;
           isValid = true;
       }
       else if (userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
       {
           decision = false;
           isValid = true;
       }
       else if (userChoice.equals(""))
       {
       System.out.println("Error! This entry is required. Try again.");
       userChoice = sc.next();
       }
       else if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") | (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
       {
        System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'Y' or 'N'. Try again.");
        userChoice = sc.next();
       }
   }
   return decision;
   }
```

NOTE: 
Code was amended to include

New console outputs(Still wrong)

FORMATTED RESULTS
Loan amount:          $5.00
Yearly interest rate: 500%
Number of years:      5
Monthly Payment:      $2.08

Continue? Y/N:

b
Error! Entry must be 'Y' or 'N'. Try again.
y
Error! Entry must be 'Y' or 'N'. Try again.
y
Enter loan amount:

Answer (score 2):

You don't set the variable userChoice to the new value. Change your last if clause to

```
System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'Y' or 'N'. Try again.");
userChoice = sc.next();
```

Comment: this somewhat worked, but when I DO enter Y for valid data, i have to do it twice back to back now. Also, my blank scenario is not working still. I will amend the question to show the console outputs

Comment: u r doing wrong using `bitwise OR` (|), rather u have to use `logical AND` (&&)

Comment: @WasifHossain, how do you figure? It cannot be both values, why would I use &&?

Comment: What happens is this: First you get to your first if clause which evaluates true, because you entered "y". Second you get to your last if clause which ALSO evaluates true because !userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") evaluates true and then you get another prompt.

Comment: @user3175451 this is about logic. just think about the case what inputs to go into this `else-if`; those which are neither 'y' nor 'n'.  let, A = caseY, B = caseN. so, we need something like this: `!(A || B)`. according to Morgans law, it implies `!A && !B`.

Answer (score 0):

Because userChoice never changes inside the loop (which is because you don't change it).

Answer (score 0):

Please look at else if part:

```
else if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") | (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
```

here you have done 2 errors:

- you have used `|`, which is `bitwise` operator, not `logical`
- the logic requires `logical AND` (`&&`) to get the cases when the input is not either `y` or `n`

SO the correct `else-if`:

```
else if (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("y") && (!userChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")))
{
    System.out.println("Error! Entry must be 'Y' or 'N'. Try again.");
    userChoice = sc.next();
}
```

Comment: This makes a whole lot of since now. Thank you. I am still wondering why my blank input line isn't working?

Comment: blank input line indicates `\n`. so i think you require `\n`. So instead of `else if (userChoice.equals(""))`, u have to use `else if (userChoice.equals("\n"))`

Comment: still nothin on this one. NetBeans noticed the newline char but testing it showed up same as before

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `sc.nextLine()` in order to catch the `Empty Blank Line`. So replace all the instances of `sc.next()` with `sc.nextLine()`